# Zend Form: How to pass parameters into the constructor?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, phpunit

I'm trying to test my form. It will be constructing other objects, so I need a way to mock them. I tried passing them into the constructor...

```
class Form_Event extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null, $regionMapper = null)
    {
        $this->_regionMapper = $regionMapper;
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

...but I get an exception:

```
Zend_Form_Exception: Only form elements and groups may be overloaded; variable of type "Mock_Model_RegionMapper_b19e528a" provided
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick look at the [sourcecode of `Zend_Form`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Form.php) shows the Exception is thrown in the `__set()` method. The method is triggered because you are assigning `$_regionMapper` on the fly when it doesn't exist.

Declare it in the class and it should work fine, e.g.

```
class Form_Event extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_regionMapper;

    public function __construct($options = null, $regionMapper = null)
    {
        $this->_regionMapper = $regionMapper;
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
```

See the chapter on [Magic Methods in the PHP Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Form` constructor looks for a specific pattern in method's names in your form. The pattern is `setMethodName`. the constructor calls the `MethodName` method and pass the parameter to it.

So you'll have this in your class :

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{

    protected $_myParameters;

    public function setParams($myParameters)
    {
        $this->_myParameters = $myParameters;
    }
```

And you pass the parameters to your form with :

```
$form = new My_Form( array('params' => $myParameters) );
```

So instead of `params` you can use any other names ( of course if it doesn't already exists in `Zend_Form` ).